# GCP add serviceaccount permission to k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, service-accounts

I'm having an issue with a step within my pipeline, more exactly:

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials $K8s_CLUSTER_NAME --zone=$GCLOUD_ZONE --project $GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID`

Which returns:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects...
```

I am not sure how to add permissions for this serviceaccount, currently I am using `.json` key for this serviceaccount in order to push images to gcr.io. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that I've missed a role from that serviceaccount, more exactly:

Kubernetes Engine Admin role

[image]

More info about the role:

[image]